# How to get rid of white outline of this AwesomeFont star?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please look at this jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z39z9y0j/3/

When you select or are hovering over a full star, the color is completely filling the star, as desired.

When you select/hover over a *half* star, however, you can see an annoying white outline. The color isn't completely filling the left half of the star.

Is there a way to get rid of this? I know it's tiny but it's also a bit infuriating.

Edit: problem is happening in Firefox and Chrome for me. Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/70uAN.png

HTML

```
<body>
<h1>Pure CSS Star Rating Widget</h1>
<fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="half" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>
</body>
```

CSS

```
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);

fieldset, label { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body{ margin: 20px; background-color:black; }
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; margin: 10px; }

/****** Style Star Rating Widget *****/

.rating { 
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating > input { display: none; } 
.rating > label:before { 
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating > .half:before { 
  content: "\f089";
     font-size: 1.25em;
  position: absolute;
}

.rating > label { 
  color: #ddd; 
 float: right; 
}

/***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

.rating > input:checked ~ label { color: #3232ff; } /* show gold star when clicked */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover, /* hover current star */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #2828cc;  } /* hover previous stars in list */

.rating > input:checked + label:hover, /* hover current star when changing rating */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, /* lighten current selection */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #4c4cff;  }
```

Comment: im not seeing it on chrome on mac. can you post a screen shot?

Comment: I'm also not seeing in Opera

Comment: Problem can be seen in Firefox and in Maxthon/IE.

Comment: Whoops, should have specified that I am using Firefox and Chrome. I will post a screenshot. Here: http://i.imgur.com/1t0Pf37.png

Comment: So the problem is that you display left half of each star and then whole star. So when user hovers over a half-star, whole-star is not being colored and its white background can be seen from under half-star (it's a flaw in some browsers rendering algorithm I guess). Maybe you should try to make half-star a little bit bigger? Or instead of using whole-star, just use mirror reflection of half-star?

Comment: Thanks :D I just tweaked the font-size and margins of half-star and it works great now. Much appreciated!

Comment: You should definitely post a solution as an answer then! If you can post tweaked HTML and CSS it could be helpfull for others.